# How do you make a Node move forever in one direction?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm trying to make a vertical endless runner like Doodle Jump in SpriteKit (Xcode 7 beta), but can't figure out how to constantly move a `Node` upwards.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    
    makeBackground()
   
    // Bubble
    
    let bubbleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bubble.png")
    
    bubble = SKSpriteNode(texture: bubbleTexture)
    
    bubble.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        
    bubble.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubbleTexture.size().height/2)
    bubble.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    bubble.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    
    let float = SKAction.moveToY(+yScale, duration: 0.2)
    
    bubble.SKAction.repeatActionForever(runAction(float))
    
    self.addChild(bubble)
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Subclass `SKSpriteNode` and modify the sprite position in the overridden `update` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so happen to see your post here after having answered your latest one; and I thought I would answer it as well.

What you just need is the following, which tells `SKAction` to repeat an action as parameter:

```
let float = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveToY(+yScale, duration: 0.2))

bubble.runAction(float)
```

***As a side note:***

In Swift, it's ok to name your vars like, for instance, `float`. But it is widely frowned upon because there is a first-class variable, namely, `float`. But in Swift, float is with an upper case; hence, no conflict here. However, to save our foreheads from being snapped by senior programmers every once and a while, we could name your action as, for instance, "**floating**", which I find it fitting due to the "**-ing**" (**continuous verb form** or **gerund**) that conveys a sense of action.

Comment: incase anyone is looking `let float = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveTo(y: +yScale, duration: 0.2))

        player.run(float)` is the updated code as per ios 13+